# how to sql query without changing the value in the query?

Tags: php, mysql

So i know the question sounds weird but I did not know how to describe it. Let me show you.

I have a page index.php that has an:

```
<a ref="videos/vid.php?id=' . $tag["video_tag"] .'">
```

that `$tag["video_tag"]` in my DB is a category and assigned a value lets say 3

Now on my other page videos.php is loaded when someone clicks that a href.
At this point my query pulls the correct videos by matching that category value of 3 to the `videos.video_tag_id` (which should do that) BUT!! it changes the id of the video. That is what is happening with this query because I inspect element and view the `id=3` on all the videos.

This query is pulling the right videos but then changing the actual id on the videos when they are listed on the page

Kind of like if netflix matched "show-1 " to six other "show2-6" but you cant load the "shows2-6" because the unique id's are all the same. The query is changing that and I do not know how to fix it.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM videos,category WHERE videos.video_tag_id = category.video_tag AND videos.video_tag_id = ' . $categoryId . ' ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6';
```

Thank you

Comment: Id is not specific and that is the reason of this mix up. make this query like select videos.*, category.id, category.name .... 
means need to specify select fields.

Comment: Please show the php loop where you build the html, the html generated, and your expected html

Comment: @NaveedRamzan yess!! thank you. I'm still learning and I'm glad you were able to show me something new today.

Comment: You welcome, you can up vote and make it correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Share your table structure. I think, In your query, id field of category table and videos table is ambiguous. Try to alias your field names.

```
$sql = "SELECT v.*,c.*,v.id as video_id FROM videos v left join category c ON v.video_tag_id = c.video_tag where v.video_tag_id = " . $categoryId . " ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 6";
```

Try this.